# easyXDM form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm in the process of converting my jquery ajax calls to use easyXDM. How might I go about doing something like this:

```
xhr.request({
    url: "someurl",
    method: "POST",
    data: $("#formid").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements      
}, function(rpcdata){
    // do stuff
});
```

My issue is with serializing the form's content. It appears that easyXDM is expecting json. Is there a simple way to convert my form to json? Or is there a way to tell easyXDM to use a standard query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/